# What is the difference between PHP and libapache2_mod_php

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, apache2, system-administration

I’m new to system administration and while launching oho files with Apache 2 server I had to install php on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried the basic `sudo apt-get install php`, which only loaded a blank page (php file).

But installing `libapache2_mod_php` solved my problem.

I want to understand the differences .

Comment: `php` is just a binary that can execute php code, much like `java`. `libapache2_mod_php` is a php binary that is designed and compiled to work with the Apache webserver, so that Apache that interpret php and handle it. Apache can't know if you have a php binary unless you give it the very specific instructions that you have: insert `libapache2_mod_php`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's pretty simple: Apache is WWW Server, PHP - a interpretter. By `libapache2_mod_php` library, the Apache can send request to the PHP, which builts website, sends rendered HTML (or whatever else) to the Apache, and it is later responsed to the user.

The flow is something like that:
[image]

without that library, the Apache don't know what is `.php` file, and recognizes it like raw file which can be downloaded, without being interpreted by PHP (sometimes it's very dangerous, for example when you are storing passwords in PHP file).

Answer (score 6):

`libapache2_mod_php` is the plugin in `Apache` webserver that interprets `.php` files (and others, depends on how you configure it) instead of serving the `.php` files as is (otherwise you would get the `php` code in your page).

The module is also a bit faster, since it runs within the `Apache` process rather than a separate executable each time the script needs to be interpreted. But they use the same underlying libraries.